# CAML query get listitems between a specified Row Index Boundary

Tags: 2007, caml-query

Is it possible to get listitems between a specified Row Index Boundary from a list using CAML

Ex: if there are 10000 records I would like to fetch records between 201 - 250

Answer (score 2):

This link has some info about generating pages of results in a CAML query, I have heard that this is ill-advised, though the function detailed in the article seems like a good solution:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dbadki/caml-query-execution-using-pagination-for-custom-columns)

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code in your solutions-

SPQuery w = new SPQuery() ;
 w.RowLimit = 10;
 w.Query = "1570";

Comment: SPQuery w = new SPQuery() ;
        w.RowLimit = 50;
        w.Query = "<Where><Gt><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Counter'>1570</Value></Gt></Where>";

Comment: The problem is that ID's don;t have to be consecutive, if say item 100 to 300 are deleted, those id's are gone. Once an item has been created, ID's don't change. so querying for 201 - 250 will return an empty result